# I manually Deleted my database from pgAdmin now Makemigration doesnt work

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using postgresql as my database and I am using Pgadmin as a management tool. I was having an issue and I learned I need to use "python manage.py myapp zero" So This was universal solution in Stackoverflow for my problem and It didnt work even after whatever I did. So I had the genius idea of deleting the database from pgadmin and recreating again. Since there was nothing important in it. Now I cant makemigration. and Cloning app from Github didnt solve my problem. What can I do?

Main Error I am getting when tried to makemigration:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.BadMigrationError
```

Edit: I tried to delete my migrations folder from app and run

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = 'app_name'
```

command on the database. I got an error there as well

```
"django_migrations" obeject does not exist. On my database management tool.
```

Comment: if you deleted the database you'll need to recreate one named as you had before and assign user rights to it (the user you have specified in settings.py).

Comment: Try deleting the database and do NOT recreate it. Let Django handle that.

Answer (score 0):

If you've deleted the DB then you can go ahead and recreate it.

You're settings.py file should let you know the creds to use for it but the commands for postgres are:

Creating user

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser <username>
```

Creating Database

```
$ sudo -u postgres createdb <dbname>
```

Giving the user a password

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql=# alter user <username> with encrypted password '<password>';
```

Granting privileges on database

```
psql=# grant all privileges on database <dbname> to <username> ;
```